# Getting this error when using Babel and Webpack on React DnD project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-2, react-dnd

Here is the problem, when using **plain ReactJS** (no React DnD), Babel and Webpack compile my .js files **flawlessly**, but **when trying to use React DnD** in my project, this **error** occurred when compiling js using Webpack and Babel:

```
ERROR in ./~/disposables/modules/index.js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] D:\MyProject\React_002\node_modules\disposables\modules\index.js: Using removed Babel 5 option: D:\MyProject\React_002\node_modules\disposables\.babelrc.stage - Check out the corresponding stage-x presets http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets
    at Logger.error (D:\MyProject\React_002\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\logger.js:41:11)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (D:\MyProject\React_002\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:220:20)
    at OptionManager.init (D:\MyProject\React_002\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:368:12)
    at File.initOptions (D:\MyProject\React_002\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:212:65)
    at new File (D:\MyProject\React_002\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:135:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (D:\MyProject\React_002\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipeline.js:46:16)
    at transpile (D:\MyProject\React_002\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:48:20)
    at Object.module.exports (D:\MyProject\React_002\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:163:20)
 @ ./~/react-dnd/lib/decorateHandler.js 41:19-41
 @ ./~/react-dnd/lib/DragSource.js
 @ ./~/react-dnd/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/js/Container.js
 @ ./src/js/script.js
```

this is my **webpack.config.js** file

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/script.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: '/node_modules/'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

this is my **.babelrc** file

```
{
  "presets" : ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

and this is my **package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "React_002",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "babel": "babel",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --watch",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dnd": "^2.3.0",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

How to solve this? and **what are the cause** for this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually excluding `node_modules` from the rule. You passed in a string that corresponds to the absolute path `/node_modules/`, that is the `node_modules` directory in `/`, the root of your file system. It should be a regular expressions and `/regex/` is the the regular expression literal syntax, but if you add quotes around it, it becomes a string (similar to what would happen if you put quotes around an array literal). See also [MDN - Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Your rule should be:

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  exclude: /node_modules/
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, minor detail missed by me.